# View play counts on iPad or iPhone?

Tags: ios, music.app

Is it possible to view play counts on iPad, or iPhone, in the Music app, like one can in iTunes?

I am running iOS 6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Music app is pretty limited in terms of the metadata it displays. At the moment it's not possible to view the play counts for songs.

Third party apps can access your music collection, but I'm not sure how much metadata is exposed to them. It may be possible to see play counts with a third party app, but I don't know for sure, nor do I know of any apps that do this.

Answer (score 1):

There's an app for iOS 7 than now allows you to do it, it's called [PlayCounts](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/playcounts/id806182496). It allows you to create playlist on the fly by selecting play counts of the songs, and see how many times you have played each song.

Comment: Could you add a link to the app so people don't have to search for it?

Comment: Looks like the app is no longer available in the App Store?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking for the answer to this in 2017, the previously mentioned PlayCounts app seems to be no longer available. There's a free app called [Song Data](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/song-data/id530392488?mt=8&uo=4&at=11l6hc&ct=fnd) that works for this now.

Comment: Awesome tip by Josh. App works great and tracks back past plays.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for a way to do this in these modern days, the ability to view play count stats is still not built into the Music app on iOS, though it is on macOS. The recommended apps aren’t on the App Store any longer or aren’t being updated, so I built my own. :)

[Music Info](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/id1521580618?mt=8) lets you select a song to view its info - play count, last played, and other metadata. It works inside the Music app too with the share sheet action.

Maybe one day Apple will build this into Music but until then this app will do the trick!